# keep same inodes metadata with rsync or ignore metadata with du

Tags: bash, rsync, metadata, inode, du

I'm trying to synchronize two folders from a remote computer.
I want to use `rsync` to send the folder, and `du` to check if the space used is identical on the remote computer.

The problem is even with a rsync success the metadata is not same for folders. (folder with a lot of files inside)

```
du -sb FOLDER
```

Doesn't give me the same number on the remote computer.

Comment: `-b` will count the block sizes that depends on the file system layouts and position of free blocks to allocate new data..try just `du -s` or a more readable `du -sh`

Comment: tried already, the problem is the same : 172008 on my computer,
171996 on the remote computer

Comment: Are the two computers using the same file system? We're talking about a difference of 8 bytes here, does it really matter? Just use `diff` to compare the folders instead.

Comment: both are ext4, how to use diff on a folder over ssh ?

Comment: I found two useful links: [Why do two directory hierarchies that are in sync have different sizes?](http://superuser.com/questions/442539/why-do-two-directory-hierarchies-that-are-in-sync-have-different-sizes) and [Does rsync verify files copied between two local drives?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30970/does-rsync-verify-files-copied-between-two-local-drives)